# Python version issues

Tags: python, mac-osx

I have a Mac which uses [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) to have multiple versions of Python installed and use the `python_select` application to switch between them.

Currently, this Mac has OS 10.6.6, which comes with Python 2.6.1 installed as `/usr/bin/python`. Using MacPorts, I've installed the `python27`, `python31`, and `python_select` ports and now have this issue: python_select seems to not be switching the default python properly:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ python -V
Python 2.6.1
$ /usr/bin/python -V
Python 2.6.1
$ sudo python_select python27
Selecting version "python27" for python
$ which python
/opt/local/bin/python
$ ls -l /opt/local/bin/python
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin    24B Mar 18 10:24 /opt/local/bin/python -> /opt/local/bin/python2.7
$ python -V
Python 2.6.1           # <-- Wrong!!!
$ /opt/local/bin/python -V
Python 2.7.1           # <-- Why are you not default?
```

So, after running `python_select`, `which python` seems to think that the `/opt/local/bin` version is going to be used, but in reality, it seems that the `/usr/bin` one is taking precedent unless I specifically call the `/opt/local/bin` one.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is perfectly answered in the response to a StackOverflow question:

[How to make Python select work for python command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768881/how-to-make-python-select-work-for-python-command)

Comment: Thank you! I had an extra PATH append in my bash_profile that was throwing it off.